# SyntaxError Unexpected Token in trying to use getUserMedia (next.js app)

Tags: syntax, next.js, getusermedia

Trying to set up an app using getUserMedia through Next.js. When trying to create a component that can fetch the media, I get a syntax error.

Tried to find other ways of getting the data, but it seems like getUserMedia is the best one for my purposes. Next.js is also the preferred framework, though I'm no expert in it.

This is how I'm trying to set up the component:

```
const Recorder = () => (

        var constraints = {audio: true, video: true};

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then(funtion(mediaStream) {
            var video = document.querySelector('video');
            video.srcObject = mediaStream;
            video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
                video.play();
            };
        })
        .catch(function(err) {console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);})
)

export default Recorder;
```

When I try to run the app, I get a SyntaxError on the third line...

EDIT: Fixed the formatting of the code

Comment: Can you try adding `window.` in the beginning of the 3rd line? Like so: `window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)`

Comment: Sorry, SO did something weird with the formating of the code. The third line is the one with

var constraints

Comment: WHat's the syntax error then? Can you show the entire log output?

Comment: Maybe `.then(funtion(mediaStream) {` should be `.then(function(mediaStream) {`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe trying with await?

```
try {
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
        video.play();
    };
}
catch(err) {
    console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
}
```

I had the same issue using await, when I changed it to .then() it started working, but I don't really know the reason why it was failing, they should both work.